# A confusion about the notation in Ernst S. Aber Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

I recently read the topic in chap 4 and chap 5 of Ernest S. Abers' book, Quantum Mechanics.

In the section 4.2.5, he wrote: From Section 3.3.3 you know how the $D^{(j)}(J_i)$ acts on the $2j+1$ states $|j,m\rangle,\ -j\leq m\leq j.$ The states are eigenstates of $D^{(j)}(\bar{J_z})$

$$
D^{(j)}(\bar{J_z})|j,m\rangle=m|j,m\rangle
$$

I read and checked the section 1.2.3-1.2.4. $\bar{J_i}$ is the generator of rotation operator $\bar{R}.$ Here, which kind of operators does he want to talk about? The case of $\bar{J_i}$ or the angular momentum in quantum mechanics $J_i$? I also checked section 4.3 when he talked about the spin-1 representation in $|j,m\rangle$ he still wrote $D^{(j)}(\bar{J_i})$

Note: $D(g)$ is called a representation of a Lie group element $g$. $\bar{R}$ is the geometrical rotation operator and $\bar{J}$ is the generator of $\bar{R}$.

Comment: The generator of rotations *is* the angular momentum operator!

Comment: I am still confused though: I assume $D$ is a displacement operator here, ie that it is a rotation operator? Then perhaps you meant to write $D^{(j)}(J_z)|j,m\rangle=\exp(im)|j,m\rangle$ or something?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Usually, $D^{(j)}(J_z)$ denotes the spin-j representation matrix of the angular momentum operator $J_z$. $D$ is a map from the abstract Lie algebra to a matrix group. So it is not a rotation operator, which is at the Lie group level, not the Lie algebra level.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Thank you for your reply.  D meant representation. I am sorry I do not express it clearly. Because he use $D^{(j)}(\bar{J_z})|j,m\rangle=m|j,m\rangle$ So I am confused which cases he meant. Because $J_z$ in quantum mechanics and $\bar{J_z}$ in geometrical space act on different vector spaces.

Comment: @HsuBill it sounds like you just answered your own question... angular momentum operators can be represented in many different vector spaces, and one such vector space is spanned by the states $|j,m\rangle$, in which the representation of the rotation generator $\bar{J}_z$ is the angular momentum operator $J_z$

Comment: More explicitly: $D^{(j)}(\bar{J_z})=J_z$

Answer (score 1):

The whole point is that you can represent rotation operators and their generators in any spin-$j$ representation spanned by the basis states $|j,m\rangle$ with $m\in (-j,-j+1,\cdots,j)$. If you write out the angular momentum operators, with matrix elements
$$\langle j,m|J_z|j,n\rangle =m\,\delta_{m,n}$$
and
$$\langle j,m|(J_x\pm i J_y)|j,n\rangle =\sqrt{j(j+1)-n(n\pm 1)}\,\delta_{m,n\pm1}$$ that satisfy the usual commutation relations like $[J_x,J_y]=iJ_z$, these can be used to furnish a spin-$j$ representation of the generators $\bar{J_i}$ of rotations and the rotation operators $\bar{R}$, through
$$R(\mathbf{r})=\exp(i \mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{J}).$$ This is indeed a rotation operator because it enables the transformations
$$R(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{J}R(\mathbf{r})^\dagger=\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{J},$$ where $\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{r})$ is the $3\times 3$ matrix representation of the rotation $\bar{R}(\mathbf{r})$, as can be verified using Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff. The entire connection is that every element from both the Lie group and the Lie algebra can be replaced by the quantum angular momentum operator associated with spin-$j$ and it will still satisfy all of the algebraic and group properties; equivalently, every spin-$j$ system can be used to construct a representation of SU(2).

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! It helps!